# Creating a "bitmask" from several boolean numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert several masks (boolean arrays) to a bitmask with numpy, while that in theory works I feel that I'm doing too many operations.

For example to create the bitmask I use:

```
import numpy as np

flags = [
    np.array([True, False, False]),
    np.array([False, True, False]),
    np.array([False, True, False])
]

flag_bits = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int8)
for idx, flag in enumerate(flags):
    flag_bits += flag.astype(np.int8) << idx  # equivalent to flag * 2 ** idx
```

Which gives me the expected "bitmask":

```
>>> flag_bits 
array([1, 6, 0], dtype=int8)

>>> [np.binary_repr(bit, width=7) for bit in flag_bits]
['0000001', '0000110', '0000000']
```

However I feel that especially the casting to `int8` and the addition with the `flag_bits` array is too complicated. Therefore I wanted to ask if there is any NumPy functionality that I missed that could be used to create such an "bitmask" array?

Note: I'm calling an external function that expects such a bitmask, otherwise I would stick with the boolean arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach to directly get to the string *bitmask* with `boolean-indexing` -

```
out = np.repeat('0000000',3).astype('S7')
out.view('S1').reshape(-1,7)[:,-3:] = np.asarray(flags).astype(int)[::-1].T
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: flags
Out[41]: 
[array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)]

In [42]: out = np.repeat('0000000',3).astype('S7')

In [43]: out.view('S1').reshape(-1,7)[:,-3:] = np.asarray(flags).astype(int)[::-1].T

In [44]: out
Out[44]: 
array([b'0000001', b'0000110', b'0000000'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

---

Using the same matrix-multiplication strategy as dicussed in detail in [`@Marat's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42058173/3293881), but using a vectorized scaling array that gives us `flag_bits` -

```
np.dot(2**np.arange(3),flags)
```

Comment: Hehe, I actually wanted an integer array as result. The stringification was more to show what the bitmask represents (I didn't know if that term is common knowledge). :)

Comment: @MSeifert Ah I see. Well I assumed that string as the bitmask :)

Comment: I suspect not using `**` would be faster: `np.dot(1<<np.arange(3, dtype=np.int8),flags)`

Answer (score 2):

How about this (added conversion to `int8`, if desired):

```
flag_bits = (np.transpose(flags) << np.arange(len(flags))).sum(axis=1)\
             .astype(np.int8)
#array([1, 6, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: One suggestion: Instead of `np.array` and `flags.T` you could do it in one: `(np.transpose(flags) << np.arange(len(flags))).sum(axis=1)`. However I can't seem to force the `sum` to return an `int8` array. It always uses `int32`.

Comment: Why would you care about about `int8`, if you convert it to a string, anyway? (But nonetheless I added the conversion to the answer).

Comment: The string-version was more meant as illustration what the bitmask is - not the expected result. I'm a bit concerned about memory, I'm using 6 shape `(12000, 12000)` boolean arrays and the intermediate `np.transpose(flags)<<np.arange(len(flags))` array is a bit "big" with dtype `int64` (even with `int32`).

Comment: But doesn't matter, your answer is working as expected!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = np.array(2**i for i in range(1, np.shape(flags)[1]+1))
>>> np.dot(flags, x)
array([1, 2, 2])
```

How it works: in a bit mask, every bit is effectively an original array element multiplied by a degree of 2 according to its position, e.g. `4 = False * 1 + True * 2 + False * 4`. Effectively this can be represented as matrix multiplication, which is really efficient in numpy.

So, first line is a list comprehension to create these weights: x = [1, 2, 4, 8, ... 2^(n+1)].

Then, each line in flags is multiplied by the corresponding element in x and everything is summed up (this is how matrix multiplication works). At the end, we get the bitmask

Comment: ok, but why is the result wrong? I want `[1, 6, 0]` and this is giving me `[1, 2, 4]`.

Comment: two reasons: I was using different values for testing and I'm summing up by lines while question goes by columns. To go by columns, just swap matrixes or transpose flags

Comment: The `flags` have to be transposed (`flags.T`) before the dot product is calculated.

Comment: For large `flags` I think `np.dot(x, flags)` will be more efficient than `flags.T`

Comment: There is still something wrong: The `2**i for i in range(1, np.shape(flags)[1]+1)` should be a list comprehension (the generator threw an error) and when I use this I get `[1, 2, 2]` which is still not the wanted `[1, 6, 0]` (or `[2, 12, 0]` if I transpose the flags first which seems to be the doubled expected result).

Comment: `flags.T` is very efficient, because it simply exchanges the indexes. It creates a new view, not a new array.

Comment: @Marat Just use : `np.dot(2**np.arange(3),flags)`, simple and sweet.

Comment: @Divakar Could you put that `np.dot` solution in your answer? That seems the most straight-forward and simplest approach! (And it even supports the `out`-argument, which will come in very handy because the real boolean arrays are quite big!)